# Unable to printf() char array in c

Tags: c, printf, c-strings

I don't seem to be understanding how `printf()` formats the output of char arrays in C. I have a bit of code whose purpose is to translate an integer into a string of binary characters, and print it. The code works up to the point where I go to print the string returned from `integerToString()`, because it doesn't print the contents of the string.

I've checked gdb to ensure that both `res` and `str` contained an array of the correct values before the `printf()` call. I've also tried printing `*res` instead of just `res`, but that returns `(null)`. What am I missing? Is there something about pointers that I am not grasping?

Thanks much in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main () {   
  printf("Please enter a positive integer: ");
  unsigned int input;

  scanf("%d", &input);

  char* res = integerToString(input);
  printf("Represented in binary that integer is: %s\n", res);
}

char* integerToString(unsigned int number){
  unsigned int value = number; 

  char* str;
  str = malloc(33); //32 bits for the string, +1 null value on the end

  unsigned int i = 31;

  while (i > 0){
    str[i] = value % 2;
    value /= 2;
    i--;
  }
  str[32] = '\0';
  return(str); 
}
```

Comment: `printf("%032b", input)` isn't good enough?

Comment: `str[i] = value % 2` should be `str[i] = value % 2 + '0'`

Comment: Hint: Do you want to fill your character array with characters or numbers? `'0'` and `0` are not the same thing.

Comment: @tadman: `%b` is not standard C – though it may be fairly widely available.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler True enough. It's fairly ubiquitous but you never know, right?

Comment: You should think about whether to use a straight counting loop (`for (int i = 31; i > 0; i--)` instead of the `while` loop.

Comment: Never call `malloc` without calling `free`!

Comment: There's also the problem that the code doesn't store anything at `str[0]` because the body of the `while` loop only runs when `i > 0`. When counting down from some number to zero, the loop should be `for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: Should have mentioned that this is for school. Prof. wants us to use `malloc()` and to remote into a CentOS machine just to standardize compilation. The idea is that it's a char array, not a numbers array, but casting the numbers to characters hasn't worked either.

Comment: If the Prof wants you to use `malloc()`, he also wants you to use `free()`.  Always call `free()` once for each `malloc()`.  And use [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/) to find out where you have leaks or other memory abuses.

Comment: The [ASCII character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is often used. And in ASCII, the character `'0'` does not have the value 0. In fact, it's 48 decimal. And `'1'` is 49.

Comment: @user3386109 I've tried the for loop, but for some reason the compiler barks at me about C99 mode, and I'm trying to keep the program as basic as possible to avoid getting points docked

Comment: @LordValkyrie You tried my first comment? The second comment from the top?

Comment: @user3386109 Yup, just now, to no avail :(

Comment: @user3386109 tried that as well. While I don't get a c99 error, I am still getting a blank output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bit `str[i] = value % 2;` is assigning 0 or 1 to characters in your array,  but the `printf` is expecting a string, so you want to assign the ASCII character for zero or one. You are currently assigning a mixture of nulls and SoH (start of header, control-A). Since ASCII one is one more than ASCII zero:

```
str[i] = value % 2 + '0'; /* ASCII zero plus this bit's value */
```

In addition, the loop stops at i = 0, so str[0] is never set.  Luckily/unluckily it must contain the binary value 0.

Comment: Tried this with the current code, and still not getting it to output anything.. although you're right, I didn't take into consideration the Ascii conversions

Comment: I updated the answer @LordValkyrie - looks like the problem is the missing assignment of str[0]

Comment: still not getting anything. I'm using the loop that user3386109 suggested `for (i = 31; i >= 0; i--)` as well as your ascii fix, to no avail.

Comment: I fixed the loop in my code (after writing the original answer) with this: `  unsigned int i = 32;

  while (i > 0){
    i --;
` and that worked for me. (One up the start value, move the decrement to the start of the loop.)

Comment: That did the trick! I guess I must have had all my values offset by one in the array or something. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

As cupcake points out, you have problems in you conversion, but I think the reason for the null is the missing declaration for integerToString.
Because the definition of this function is after its use, C will assume that it returns an int -- this is a default action.   If you are on a 64 bit system this will throw away many of the returned bits.   You can resolve this by either adding a forward declaration, or reversing the order of the two functions in your source.   The latter is an idiom adopted by many C programmers to avoid the clumsy forward declarations.

Usually, your compiler will complain when it later finds a function definition which doesn't match the one it assumed.   If your compiler doesn't do this, you really should get one that does.  There are lots of free compilers available these days, and really no reason to put up with a lousy one.

If you ignored your compiler complaining about this, then you shouldn't have.

Comment: Required to use gcc 4.8.5 RedHat. And I neglected to post it because I'm dumb, but I have the following function prototype at the top: `char*         integerToString(unsigned int number);`